# FATAL ha.BootstrapStandby: Unable to fetch namespace information from active NN

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, high-availability, namenode

[image]

unable start standby namenode. I have verified my configurations from official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase value of `ipc.maximum.data.length` property in `core-site.xml` file. Make sure all nodes has same value for this property.

Note: 
default value is 64Mb.
You will have to restart services once value is changed.